# Sharepoint2010 Lists Lookup

Tags: list, lookup-column, column

I'm creating 3 lists using Sharepoint 2010 UI.
The lists and relationship are as follows:
Training (parent) -> Training Instance (child, look up Training ) -> Training Session (grandchild,lookup Training Instance)

The problem is when I try to look up the Training Instance from the Training Session list, the Training(look up field) is not visible. All other fields except for the lookup field in the Training Instance lists is visible in the Training Session.

Is it not possible to go beyond child list.
Is there any way that I could achieve the same thing (parent -> child -> grandchild).

Any help is very much apperciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are doing the lookup? SPServices below is one way but there are plenty of others depending on how you are doing the lookups.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to answer my question. Im creating the lists using Sharepoint 2010 UI. And it is there, when i create a column that I do the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this myself.  It seems you can show grandparent-parent-child relationships in an OOB list view, but the view itself has to be created using CAML. This worked for me: http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/joins-and-projections-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, you cannot directly pull the value of the grand-parent from within the list.

One option would be to run a workflow that will look up the parent list to find the grand-parent.

Another option would be to display both lists on the page and use a Web Part connection.

I'll add that you usually do it the other way around: select the grand-parent before selecting the parent (e.g. select the country, then the state). In this case, you could be interested in Marc Anderson's SPServices library:

[http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

This same library has a couple other options that could help in your case:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for trying to answer my question. I'm not doing cascading dropdown. It's just three different lists, like I explain above. The problem is when I try to insert a training session using the training session list via the built in form, the training field (Look up field, target is Training Instance) does not contain any value.

Comment: Three different lists with parent-child relationship - yes, that's what I meant by cascading. What I meant in the second part of my reply is that instead of trying to address the current issue you could change your process.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you can't add a column to the Training Instance list based on the Training lookup field in the Training Session list. This is the expected behaviour - you can't create a calculated field based on the lookup either.

The "join" between the three lists is still there. Using custom code you can make it visible, because the object model will allow you to follow the chain up through the heirarchy. Unfortunately it is not possible to show this using the out-of-the-box list views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just to make it more specific. The problem is when I try to insert a training session using the training session list via the built in form (by clicking the add new item link), the training field in the training session lists which is a look up field(target is Training Instance) does not contain any value.